# Fast set indexing data structure for superset retrieval

Tags: indexing, set

I am given a set of sets:

```
{{a,b}, {a,b,c}, {a,c},{a,c,f}}
```

I would like to have a data structure to index those sets such that the following "lookup" is executed fast: find all supersets of a given set.

For example, given the set {a,c} the structure would return

```
{{a,b,c},{a,c,f}}
```

but not {a,b}.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want a generic algorithm answer I suggest you post on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ instead. SO is more for questions about specific implementation problems.

Comment: Thank you Joachim. I will post my question there.